# concatening strings in R repetatively

Tags: r, string

Suppose I build mystring in a for loop as followings in r:

```
mystring = ""
colorIndex = 17
for(i in 1:ncol(myTable)){

     mystring = paste(mystring, paste("$('td:eq(",i, ")', nRow).attr('title', full_text);", sep = ""))
     mystring = paste(mystring, paste("$('td:eq(",i,")', nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');", sep = ""))
     mystring = paste(mystring, "if(aData[",colorIndex,"] == 0){
                                      $(nRow).css('background-color','#f8f8ff')
                                  }else if(aData[",colorIndex,"]==1){
                                      $(nRow).css('background-color','#9EFAC5')
                                  }else{
                                      $(nRow).css('background-color','#FAF99E')
                                  };", sep ="")

}
```

Now, suppose my table had 60 columns. I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to do this. Do I need to make one large string, with a special character and then grep out the character? How to iterate over the i efficiently is throwing me. However, given how slow R is with strings, I would prefer not to do this in a loop.

Comment: You could use an apply function, which might perform better, and might leave the code looking a bit cleaner.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: But how would that concatenate at the end?

Comment: just pondering aloud, would this be easier in javascript itself?

Comment: Perhaps -- but my javascript is somewhat limited. what would be the bet way to do it directly in javascript?

Comment: post it as a javascript question? there is a huge community on js here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all because `paste` is vectorized:

```
i <- 1:ncol(myTable)

yourstring <- 
  paste(
    paste0(
    paste0(" ", "$('td:eq(",i, ")', nRow).attr('title', full_text);"),
    " ",
    paste0("$('td:eq(",i,")', nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');"),
    "if(aData[",colorIndex,"] == 0){
                                   $(nRow).css('background-color','#f8f8ff')
                               }else if(aData[",colorIndex,"]==1){
                                   $(nRow).css('background-color','#9EFAC5')
                               }else{
                                   $(nRow).css('background-color','#FAF99E')
                               };"
    ), 
    collapse = "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `glue` for this, because it makes things look cleaner, and put combinations in a data frame in advance, such that you don't need the loop:

```
myTable <- iris
mystring <- "your string with some glue-elements in it: i = {paste_df$i} and colorIndex = {paste_df$colorIndex}"
paste_df <- data.frame(i = seq_len(ncol(myTable)), colorIndex = 17)
string <- glue::glue(mystring)

# or, a little messy but the same, with paste0:
string <- paste0("your string with some glue-elements in it: i = ", 
                 paste_df$i, " and colorIndex = ", paste_df$colorIndex)

# and in the end, collapse the string:
paste0(string, collapse = "")
```